# Resolution properties for python's OpenCV and uv4l camera driver

Tags: python, opencv, raspicam

I've followed [this tutorial](http://mitchtech.net/raspberry-pi-opencv/) to install OpenCV 2.3.1 in raspberry and it has worked fine. I've also installed from [here](http://www.linux-projects.org/modules/section/index.php?op=viewarticle&artid=14) the uv4l raspicam driver. But now I need to modify some capture properties as the width and the height of the frames.
So I've tried with:

```
import cv2
cv2.namedWindow("preview")
vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0) #assigned by the uv4l driver
vc.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH,640.0)
vc.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT,480.0)

if vc.isOpened():
    rval, frame = vc.read()
else:
    rval = False

while rval:
     cv2.imshow("preview", frame)
     rval, frame = vc.read()
     key = cv2.waitKey(33)
     if key == 27:
          break
```

but in the linux-shell it returns:

```
HIGHGUI ERROR: V4L: Initial Capture Error: Unable to load initial memory buffers
```

So I've tried also to edit those properties in the Idle shell with:

```
>>import cv2
>>vc = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
>>prop = vc.get(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)
```

it returns me always `64.0` (the default width), and when I try with:

```
>>prop = vc.set(cv2.cv.CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640.0)
```

it returns `False`

How can I set my resolution? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In order to set the height and width:

```
vc.set(3,640)
vc.set(4,480)
```

Where 640x480 is you resolution. This is just another way to what you're doing right now, so I doubt there will a different result.

---

The main issue with this is that not all cameras support all OpenCV parameters, and there's no real way to fix that without new hardware.

---

Also since you're compiling from source (as the tutorial indicates), there's a change that there was an issue when compiling or in the conf file. I'd try using the packages in the official repository and see if it works. To install:

```
sudo apt-get install libopencv-dev python-opencv
```

And since numpy is used in most places of OpenCV's python bindings:

```
sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

---

I just did a just bit of research into your exact error and it could be driver based. The last post [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=38&t=71320), shows that you might want to try a alternative driver.